# How to query data with same id in a sequence?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a archive system that has folders within folders and I have a table name folder_table.

I'm trying to create an array of parentid to use for breadcrumbs.

My question is how to query datas with same id that has sequence? (check linenum column)

See attached image for reference

[image]

This is my expected result :

[image]

is there a way i can make it works?

Thanks

Comment: Please show sample input and expected outcome as tables. Explain more detailed what you want to do and what you have tried.

Comment: Looks like your `linenum` is just a depth of an adjacency list element. Do you want to grab the whole subtree with a recursive query?

Comment: yes I just need the datas that has relation between their `folderID`. Do you have anything to suggest like add another column?

Answer (score 0):

try
select * from folder_table
where folderid in (select parentid from folder_table)
order by id desc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).